# Is it acceptable to share notes on mathematics meta?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

In response to [my question regarding the Collatz Conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383144/does-collatz-rule-3x5-have-a-bias-for-certain-loops-or-are-my-results-faulty?noredirect=1#comment4957324_2383144), I received the following comment:

"@GriffonTheorist697, I have done quite a bit of work on the Collatz problem from this angle, and I believe I can answer some of your questions. I'd like to compare notes with you. Would you be willing to correspond off of MSE? – G Tony Jacobs"

Being new to Stack Exchange, I looked at some similar questions and those answers suggested to go to Math Overflow. My only concern is Math Overflow is "For professional Mathematicians" according to its description, and I am certainly not a professional anything, just a high school student interested in math.

Would it be acceptable to post a discussion topic as broad as sharing Collatz notes, or would this be better off discussed on some other site?

Comment: Other sites encourage discussion, but StackExchange aims to collect Q&A content of a fairly definitive and concise nature.  I would look to various non-SE sites to carry out an open-ended discussion of (say) the Collatz Conjecture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematics Meta is for questions concerning Mathematics Stack Exchange, as well as the Stack Exchange network as a whole, including the underlying architecture.  (See [What's Meta?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) in the Help Center.) Questions about mathematics — and outright mathematical questions — have no place here. In fact, we have found it necessary to introduce a close reason for this:

> You posted this mathematics question on the meta site attached to the site [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/). The meta site is intended for support questions and discussions about the main site (cf. the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)). Please post your question on the main site instead: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. For further information see: [How to Ask](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959)

Such a question on the main site may be "too broad" and may also be perfectly fine. This would depend on the exact wording of the question.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with arjafi it is not acceptable for meta, and it also does not seem well-suited for the main site (or any other site in the SE network).

SE infrastructure you could use for this though is *chat.* It seems there are a few users that want to discuss about some particular subject. Thus, create a chat room for that subject.

To share actual notes chat is not a good medium, but neither is an SE site. But, as you did for your question, you could share links to external repositories and alike.

At the very moment you cannot create a chatroom as it needs 100 points. But G Tony Jacobs could. So, you could reply with the suggestion of creating a chat room to further discuss the subject.